# How to exclude specific folder in rsync?

Tags: raspbian, backup

Hi I am rsync ing and I need to exclude the folder 'Art' and 'Thumbnail' from rsync process , these two folders are inside this location

> /home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Media/localhost/3/4e23c7deb529b98f89e4c27515172af8790461b.bundle/Contents/

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync --exclude='/home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Media/localhost/3/4e23c7deb529b98f89e4c27515172af8790461b.bundle/Contents/Art --exclude '/home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex Media Server/Media/localhost/3/4e23c7deb529b98f89e4c27515172af8790461b.bundle/Contents/Thumbnail' [...]
```

or

```
rsync --exclude-from='file.txt' [...]
```

with `file.txt` containing the directories one per line:

```
/home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Media/localhost/3/4e23c7deb529b98f89e4c27515172af8790461b.bundle/Contents/Art
/home/pi/Library/Application Support/Plex\ Media\ Server/Media/localhost/3/4e23c7deb529b98f89e4c27515172af8790461b.bundle/Contents/Thumbnail
```

Comment: So exclude flag can be used multiple times! Can you show example using file.txt

Comment: Here is the problem the directories under localhost are different for each media after content it's same

Comment: Rsync works with globbing, e.g., `*`, so you should be able to use `*.bundle/Contents/Thumbnail`, presuming there are no such directories you do want to sync.  Otherwise you may have to filter this through a script.